# Read entry in a string array into a dictionary object

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have a string stored in: reviewers_list

I want to iterate through it and create a new list of dictionaries called reviewer_dicts

```
reviewers_dicts = {}
for i in reviewers_list:
    reviewers_dicts.append(i)
print(reviewers_dict)
```

I have tried this so far

Comment: If you have a string stored in reviewers_list, the name of the variable is poorly chosen.
And in the loop you'll iterate over each letter of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Many things to talk about.
First you are making a dictionary, here, not a list of dictionaries.
Secondly, a dictionary is made up of key-value pairs, not single values.

So for your example, if we wanted the keys to be `i` and the values to be empty strings we'd do like so:

```py
reviewers_dicts = {}
for i in reviewers_list:
    reviewers_dicts[i]=""
print(reviewers_dict)
```

And if you *actually* wanted a *list of dicts*, then you would do this:

```py
list_of_dicts = []
for i in reviewers_list:
    list_of_dicts.append({i:""})
print(list_of_dicts )
```